# Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1

Tags: android, firebase

estoy intentando añadir Firebase a mi proyecto de Android, sigo los pasos que indican en el asistente de añadir a tu aplicación Android y da error cuando realizó la sincronización de Gradle.

Añado el archivo google-serviles.json a mi proyecto android
[image]

Añado las siguientes lineas
[image]

Una vez añadidas las lineas anteriores Android Studio me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
    Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.0.1/google-services-4.0.1.pom
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.0.1/google-services-4.0.1.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/4.0.1/google-services-4.0.1.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/4.0.1/google-services-4.0.1.jar
Required by:
    project :
```

y como podéis observar tengo los archivos de Gradle tal y como indica el paso de añadir Firebase a Android

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle - app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.luisalbertomurciasolivella.pruebanotificaciones"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualmente se esta investigando el problema, podes chequear una pregunta similar que se abrio hoy

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53706565/error-could-not-find-com-google-gmsgoogle-services4-2-0/53709401#53709401

Como dice Doug Stevenson ( persona que trabaja en Firebase )

> Se supone que el complemento está disponible en el repositorio de
>   Google. Sin embargo, algo está mal actualmente con eso. El problema
>   está siendo investigado.

Se puede ver un issue tracker en el siguiente link sobre el problema

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347

Una solucion a corto plazo mientras este problema se arregla es el siguiente

agrega la siguiente linea bajo repositorios en Build Gradle ( modulo proyecto )

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools' }
}
```

y en el siguiente

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
        google()
    }
}
```